# What is the best way to shorten this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

Using the DRY methodology, I was wondering what could be the best way this code could be shorten. It seems to me there is too much repetition in there.

```
function back(){
    $('.back').click(function(){ 
        if($(this).hasClass('back_3')){
            $('.screen3').addClass('hidden');
            $('.screen1').removeClass('hidden');
        }else if ($(this).hasClass('back_2')){
            $('.screen2').addClass('hidden');
            $('.screen1').removeClass('hidden');
        }else if($(this).hasClass('back_4')){
            $('.screen4').addClass('hidden');
            $('.screen3').removeClass('hidden');
        }else if($(this).hasClass('back_5')){
            $('.screen5').addClass('hidden');
            $('.screen3').removeClass('hidden');
        }else if($(this).hasClass('back_6')){
            $('.screen6').addClass('hidden');
            $('.screen3').removeClass('hidden');

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A `for` loop looks sufficient ...

Comment: Before you post it there also include the relevant html structure

Comment: I don't see a strong pattern here. What decides what element had the class removed? Also, it would probably be better if you made a runnable example, and posted this on Code Review. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: what's the supposed logic? It's difficult to recognize a pattern...

Comment: @Andy Would be closed for lack of context. We don't review snippets devoid of any and all context, no point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpy extract the id of the class, then hide/show the respective classes:

```
 $('.back').click(function(){ 
  var id = this.className.split(" ").find(clss => clss.includes("back_")).split("_")[1];
  $(".screen"+id).addClass("hidden");
  $(".screen"+id>3?3:1).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: it could have multiple classes

Comment: @hitmands still the first one will be triggered only. Both in mys and the ops code.

Comment: @elyes10 glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to DRYify this code is to use `data-*` attributes to link the button to what to hide/show

eg (for first `if` branch)

```
<button class="back" data-hide=".screen3" data-show=".screen1">Back_3</button>
```

and then this

```
$('.back').click(function(){ 
    var $this = $(this);
    $($this.data("hide")).addClass("hidden");
    $($this.data("show")).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Same handler works for any `.back` button with `data-hide` and `data-show` attributes.

Comment: I wouldn't add routing logic to the DOM element... this is a Business Logic Concern

Comment: @Hitmands there is no "routing logic" in the DOM, there is attribute information. Any routing logic is in the jquery. In any case, if its routing logic the OP wanted they should use one of the myriad of routing libraries.

Comment: `hide screen 3 AND show screen 4` is routing logic.. Yes, it should have implemented some kind of routing...

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (not tested):

```
var arrScreens=[
   {hC:"back_3",screenShow:".screen3",screenHide:".screen1"]},
   {hC:"back_2",screenShow:".screen2",screenHide:".screen1"]},
]

function back(){
    $('.back').click(function(){ 
         var $this=$(this);
         $(arrScreens).each(function(i,obj) {
               if($this.hasClass(obj.hC)) {
                   $(obj.screenShow).addClass('hidden');
                   $(obj.screenHide).removeClass('hidden');
                   return false;                        
               }
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: this doesn't follow the `else if` exclusion

Comment: The `return` should do the job?! First match will exit the loop.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ return false breaks the iteration. Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would have done in your case.

```js
const routes = [
  {id: 'back_3', hide: '.screen3', show: '.screen1' },
  {id: 'back_2', hide: '.screen2', show: '.screen1' },
  {id: 'back_4', hide: '.screen4', show: '.screen3' },
  {id: 'back_5', hide: '.screen5', show: '.screen3' },
  {id: 'back_6', hide: '.screen6', show: '.screen3' },
];

function back() {
  const hiddenCls = 'hidden';
  const $back = $('.back');

  return $back.click(event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    for(const route of routes) {
      const {id, hide, show} = route;

      if($(event.currentTarget).hasClass(id)) {

        $(hide).addClass(hiddenCls);
        $(show).removeClass(hiddenCls);

        break;
      }
    }

  });
}
```